# Implicit conversion operator T() with template overloads using std::enable_if fail to compile

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, sfinae

I am writing a class in C++17 which I would like overload conversion operator for floating types as well as for some custom types. Here is the reproducible example. There are many more conversions that I need to add with templates, but if I can resolve these, the rest should be similar.

```
class A {
};

class B : public A {
};

class C: public A {
};

class Missing {
 public:
  Missing() {}
  Missing(Missing &) = default;

  template<typename T,typename=typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, T>>
  explicit constexpr operator T() const {
    return static_cast<T>(NAN);
  }

  template<typename T, class = typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<A, T>, T>>
  explicit operator T() const {
    return T();
  }


};
```

However on compilation with gcc 8.2 with std=c++17 flag, I get the following error:

```
<source>:25:12: error: 'template<class T, class> Missing::operator T() const' cannot be overloaded with 'template<class T, class> constexpr Missing::operator T() const'

   explicit operator T() const {

            ^~~~~~~~

<source>:20:22: note: previous declaration 'template<class T, class> constexpr Missing::operator T() const'

   explicit constexpr operator T() const {

                      ^~~~~~~~

Compiler returned: 1
```

I would think that using `enable_if` would prevent the operators from overloading for the same type, but looks like the compiler isn't looking at the `enable_if` on the first pass. I am not sure if I have the right syntax. Any help would be appreciated. Been at this for some time now.

---

**Update**:

Tried updating the operators to

```
  template<typename T>
  constexpr explicit operator std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, T>() const {
    return static_cast<T>(NAN);
  }

  template<typename T>
  explicit operator std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<A, T>, T>() const {
    return T();
  }
```

But now, on trying to cast the class to float:

```
int main() {
    Missing m;
    float a = static_cast<float>(m);
}
```

I get an error:

```
<source>:34:35: error: invalid static_cast from type 'Missing' to type 'float'

     float a = static_cast<float>(m);
```

Comment: The problem is that you are declaring the same member template twice, with different default arguments. The error happens before any instantiation so the default arguments are not even looked at. To solve, move `enable_if_t` out of the arguments and make it thebreturn type of the operator.

Comment: I updated the template, but now I get invalid static_cast. I will update the question with what I have tried.

Comment: Aww sorry you can't do that, this creates an undeduced context. I will make an answer with another method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are declaring the same member template twice, with different default arguments. The error happens before any instantiation so the default arguments are not even looked at.

The first impulse to solve this would be moving `enable_if_t` out of the arguments and making it the return type of the operator:

```
template<typename T>
explicit constexpr operator std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, T>>() const ...
```

But this doesn't work because `T` is undeduced context now.

So the other way to make the two templates different is to add a dummy parameter with a defalut value to *one* of them.

```
template<typename T,
         typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, T>,
         bool = true>
explicit constexpr operator T() const ...
```

The other template should be left as is.

With the two templates having different number of template parameters, they are no longer considered identical.

Comment: Or use `std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>, bool> = true` as non-type template parameter on both overloads.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to define the deduced template argument to be a defaulted pointer:

```
template
<
  typename T, 
  std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>* = nullptr
>
explicit constexpr operator T() const {
  return static_cast<T>(NAN);
}
```

I find this to be a concise and reliable way to optionally enable methods, operators and constructors.